How to install Install APSB24-18 Patch in Magento 2?
My hosting provider send me mail regarding patch installation on my store, but I want to know how I can install this patch on my store.
Adobe does not provide any kind of documentation regarding this: https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb24-18.html
Can anyone help me about this?

This patch can be applied by upgrading your magento 2 version
In the 'Solution' section on Adobe Security Bulletin , you have the version you need to update to
ex: if you have magento 2.4.6-p4 you need to update to magento 2.4.6-p5


Here is the list of commands you need to perform to update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition=2.4.6-p5 --no-update
// the option --no-update can be removed if you don't want to check which module is going to update 

composer update

rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*

bin/magento setup:upgrade
// check on your magento admin at the bottom right corner your new version

More Information on how to update
